# SQL gruping by parent ID

Tags: sql

I have data like this

```html
| ID | Child_ID | quantity | type |
|----|----------|----------|------|
|  1 |          |       28 | B    |
|  2 |        1 |       14 | S    |
|  3 |        1 |       10 | S    |
|  4 |        2 |       14 | K    |
|  5 |        2 |       10 | K    |
|  6 |        3 |       28 | P    |
|  7 |          |       10 | B    |
|  8 |        7 |        8 | S    |
|  9 |        7 |        2 | S    |
```

and I would like to get something like this

```html
| ID | B  | S  | K  | P  |
|----|----|----|----|----|
|  1 | 28 | 24 | 24 | 28 |
|  7 | 10 | 10 |    |    |
```

Comment: Please specific SQL server type

Comment: Moreover, please tell us by what criteria to _group_ your data into expected result.  And also please post what you have tried.

Comment: @Jacky SQL server and SQL are different

Comment: If possible, looks like you need to write a recursive function to find the ultimate parent id first, then use a conditional sum for each level within the "type" column.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh my bad, missing comma: "SQL, server, type"

Comment: @BartSchuijt Yes you are right. I''m trying to find ultimate parent ID first, but I do not know how.

Comment: @user1649489 what SQL engine are you using?

Comment: Also, I think the child_id attribute is meant to be named the parent_id. If it's null, ID is the parent_id.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand what exactly you're trying to do here. But this looks like a pivot could be used to accomplish something similar. For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT id, quantity, type
 FROM t) main
PIVOT
(SUM(quantity)
 FOR type in ([B], [K], [P], [S])) piv
```

Returns:

```
    id  B   K   P   S
1   1   28  NULL    NULL    NULL
2   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    14
3   3   NULL    NULL    NULL    10
4   4   NULL    14  NULL    NULL
5   5   NULL    10  NULL    NULL
6   6   NULL    NULL    28  NULL
7   7   10  NULL    NULL    NULL
8   8   NULL    NULL    NULL    8
9   9   NULL    NULL    NULL    2
```

Comment: Like @bart wrote, I'm trying to find ultimate parent ID with recursion.